# Problem Importing CAD features using arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management?

Tags: arcpy, layers, import, cad

When importing multiple CAD drawings using "arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management" and "arcpy.Merge_management" I encountered a problem.  Drawings that have line weights and elevation values assigned to some of the polyline features would not import.  When other polylines that had values of 0 for the line weights and elevations in the same drawing imported just fine.

Why would the "arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management" care about line weights or elevation Values?  Has anyone encountered this or a similar problem and found a work around?

Comment: You mention the Merge tool but it sounds like that is unrelated to where you are stuck.  Isn't this just a question about how the Make Feature Layer tool works?  If it really is an ArcPy question can you include a code snippet, please?  If it is about a single tool then can you provide more details about the parameters you are using with it instead.